# Creating data hierarchy in Power BI Model

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a model in Power BI to replicate a SSAS cube. I am able to create the model, but the underline data is having hierarchy. I know to handle hierarchy in report, but straggling to find a way to handle hierarchy in the Power BI model itself. Any clue will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, Microsoft has this *Power BI guidance documentation* on [Data modelling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema).
In Power BI you manage relations in the **Model view**.